# How to r un loocv in R with naivebayes model?

Tags: r

My following output produce accuracy:

```
data(iris)
x = iris[,-5]
y = iris$Species
train_control <- trainControl(method="LOOCV")
model <- train(x,y, trControl=train_control, method="nb")
```

But what i wish to get is the following output with probability each class belong to:

```
Model=naiveBayes(Species ~., data=iris)
Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include the packages you are using, like:

```
library(caret)
```

It looks to me like caret::train method "nb" uses NaiveBayes (from klaR package), while naiveBayes is from the e1071 package.

In any case model$finalmodel contains the model object.